# how to publish job on Simply Hired from my asp.net site

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

i need to publish job on Simply Hired from my asp.net site using Simply Hired API with C# code in my asp.net application ..??

and how to get Simply Hired API to publish job?

thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.simplyhired.com/a/publishers/overview

Comment: can you provide me an example to publish job from my site

Comment: Read the link.  At a cursory glance, it appears you have to create a job-o-matic job board, and then click on the "Advanced" tab for documentation on their XML API.

Comment: thanks  .. but can you provide  me that link

Comment: I did - in my first comment.

Comment: i can't see the "Advance" tab , can u provide me direct link for XML API?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a direct link - **unless** **you have create a job-o-matic job board**.  Do you have a job-o-matic job board?  If you do, the left hand column of the page I linked for you tells you to click on the Advanced tab. I can't tell you anything more than what is on the page that I linked.